# Regex to find mentions with full names

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that will find text with an @ sign and a full name:

e.g. "This is about @Paul Cowan"

Currently I have:

```
/(?:^|\s)(@[^@\s]*)(?=\s|$)/g
```

Which will match @Paul but not @Paul Cowan

How could I find the next word also?

Comment: How would you know if the next word belongs to the name? I recommend this read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I am going to test the matches against an array of values. If it finds a match then all well and good.

Is it possible to select the next word this way?

Comment: what is the full name of this line `This is about @Paul Cowan And His Son Cowan Junior` ?

Comment: Please edit your question, is anything that comes after @, is person name, or anything that comes after and starts with an uppercase?

Comment: @dagda1 i don't know which language you're going to use, but if you're going to match against an array, you could just detect if it starts with @paul + 1 (space) + other words (all case insensitive) and then search if it exists in your array. Though this is a tough mission ... Just one example that may explain the difficulty: `@David van der Vaart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a regexp that matches three groups, the second two optionally
You don't say what language you are using, here's some action in python

```
>>> str="my name is @paul cowen the king of rock"
>>> r=re.search('@(\w+)(\s+)?(\w+)?',str)
>>> r.groups()
('paul', ' ', 'cowen')
```

Then join them in the rest of your program
Hope this helps!